# gnuplot rowstacked histogram - don't show every xtic

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have a data file with a *lot* of rows - it is CPU usage (broken down to %user, %system, %iowait and %nice) sampled every 5 seconds over a 24 hour period, so 17280 samples all up. My input file looks like this:

```
Time              CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
17:11:05          all      4.46      0.00      0.57      0.79      0.00     94.18
17:11:10          all      2.34      0.00      0.31      0.44      0.00     96.91
17:11:15          all      2.48      0.00      0.33      0.14      0.00     97.06
```

To try to see when there periods of high CPU load, I want to plot the non-idle CPU usage over time as a histogram, and I am using something like this:

```
set key autotitle columnhead
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 1.0
plot 'sarout.csv' using "%user":xtic(1), '' using "%system", '' using "%iowait", '' using "%nice"
```

The trouble is that this is giving me an xtic (i.e. the time) on every single column, which is unreadable.

Is there a way to get the xtic to appear only on the hour? i.e. when the Time string matches "*:00:00".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot histograms don't have a conventional numerical axis. You could put a condition in the `xtic`, but that affects only the tic labels, but not the tics.

To get a normal numerical axis you must plot `with boxes`, but that doesn't allow you to stack values. Or you plot and stack `with boxxyerrorbars`:

```
set key autotitle columnhead
set style fill solid border -1
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set format x '%H'
set xtics 360

plot 'sarout.csv' using 1:(0.5*column("%user")):(60):"%user" with boxxyerrorbars, \
        '' using 1:(column("%user")+0.5*column("%system")):(60):"%system" with boxxyerrorbars,\
        '' using 1:(column("%user")+column("%system")+0.5*column("%iowait")):(60):"%iowait" with boxxyerrorbars, \
        '' using 1:(column("%user")+column("%system")+column("%iowait")+0.5*column("%nice")):(60):"%nice" with boxxyerrorbars
```

That is quite verbose to write, but gives you the best control over the tics. I cannot test this code at the moment, but it should work.